# Detecting derived class destruction from the base class

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance

## Question

In C++, the derived class destructor is called before the base class destructor on an object's destruction. Is it possible to automatically notify the base class(i.e. call a member function of the base class) on derived class destruction?

I can manually call the base class notification function in the derived class destructor, but the users would have to always remember to put that line in whenever they inherit from the base class, which I want to avoid.

## Background

I'm building a multithreading framework that an object of a class `MyObject` that inherits from a class `GeneralObject` is accessed from two different threads(the main thread and the producer thread).

When the object is destructed in the main thread, the destructor of the `MyObject` is called then the destructor of the class `GeneralObject` removes itself from the valid-object-table where all the 'valid' pointer of the polymorphic object of `GeneralObject` is stored. This stops the producer thread from accessing the object that no longer exists.

The problem is that in the brief moment between the destructor call of `MyObject` and the destructor call of `GeneralObject`, the pointer stored in valid-object-table becomes a dangling pointer. It will of course be removed in the `GeneralObject` destructor, but since the producer thread could try to access the object between that short period, this is unsafe. I need `GeneralObject`'s function that removes itself from the table to be called on the `MyObject`'s destruction.

## What I ended up doing

As @user17732522 pointed out in the comment, The pointer is already invalid when the `MyObject`'s destructor is entered, which makes my method unsafe. I adopted the solution by @HolyBlackCat where a wrapper object calles `MyObject`'s pointer removal function on its destruction, berfore the `MyObject`'s destructor is called.

Comment: Why not use a `weak_ptr` in the valid-object table?  You probably don't want entries there that are being partially destructed anyway, since it already smells like a race.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yeah that is something I would do if I can't find a good solution for this question. I just don't want to create the object with `make_shared<typename>` that would add extra typing when using the framework. And yes I would use mutex for the table to avoid any race.

Comment: Synchronization around destructors is extremely tricky (see https://youtu.be/JSjoCisIHcM?si=-LN7eRFHxxjJVFVc&t=4727 around 1:18:47 if the link doesn't work).  It's a talk by a clang developer and the timestamp is about a *very* sneaky race condition related to the vtable during destruction.

Comment: It won't work either way. Formally the lifetime of the object already ends when the derived destructor is entered. Fixing the pointer, even at the beginning of the derived destructor, is too late. Any access to the pointer will be a race on the lifetime of the object and therefore UB. The video link above gives a practical example of how this UB can manifest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most-derived class needs to be under your control. What I would do is this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper : T
{
    using T::T;
    ~Wrapper() {this->PreDestroy();}
};
```

Then you must use `Wrapper<MyObject>` instead of `MyObject`. To enforce that, I would make my own wrapper for `std::unique_ptr<T>`, where the only way to construct it (`std::make_unique()`-like) forcefully wraps the object in `Wrapper<...>`.

Comment: I like HolyBlackCat's approach best.  An alternative would be the base class has a bool flag that tracks if PreDestroy was called, and the base class destructor squawks (`assert` or `std::cerr << "blah blah\n";`) if the flag indicates the required-by-contract PreDestroy had not been called yet.

Comment: That is an elegant solution, but I was hoping to see a way that doesn't require any extra typing when creating the object. I'll accept this answer if there isn't such answer after some time.